# Pushing a simple Log string from a Google Ad Script to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set up a script which can push data from an App Script into a Google Sheet.

I have the script successfully logging what I want, which goes in the following format `Account budget is 12344`, but now I want to push this into a Google Sheet. I have set up a variable containing the URL and another variable containing the sheet name, and also a clear method to delete anything already there.

Find the code I have below:

```js
// - The link to the URL
var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'abcdefghijkl'
// - The name of the sheet to write the data
var SHEET_NAME = 'Google';


// No to be changed 
function main() { 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  sheet.clearContents();  
}


function getActiveBudgetOrder() {
  // There will only be one active budget order at any given time.
  var budgetOrderIterator = AdsApp.budgetOrders()
      .withCondition('status="ACTIVE"')
      .get();
  while (budgetOrderIterator.hasNext()) {
    var budgetOrder = budgetOrderIterator.next();
    Logger.log("Budget Order Amount " + budgetOrder.getSpendingLimit());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to clear the entire Sheet every time you extract the data this should work for you.  You will need to set the url and shtName variables.

```
function getActiveBudgetOrder() {

  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/';
  var shtName = 'Sheet1';
  var arr = [];

  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName(shtName);

  // There will only be one active budget order at any given time.
  var budgetOrderIterator = AdsApp.budgetOrders()
      .withCondition('status="ACTIVE"')
      .get();
  while (budgetOrderIterator.hasNext()) {
    var budgetOrder = budgetOrderIterator.next();
    arr.push(["Budget Order Amount " + budgetOrder.getSpendingLimit()]);
  }

  sht.clearContents();
  sht.getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);

}
```